# Mouse over event NOT re-triggering once item has been selected

Tags: excel, vba

I have been struggling on this one for a few days now and can not seem to work it out. I am using images as buttons, which have a mouseover effect that changes the border to GREEN when the mouse is hovered over them, apart from them flashing on hover, this works fine apart from when the problem kick in, see below for problem.

I then have an onClick event which changes the border to GREEN if that image/button is selected, this indicates that this is active as the click opens a multi page, this bit also seems to work fine as I had to put in a repaint event in as it would not work without it. `UserForm1.Repaint`.

**The Problem I am having**

Once a image/button has been selected and then de-selected the mouse over event NO longer works on the image/button that was previously selected.

Example, If I scroll the mouse over the two buttons below, their borders will change to green on hover, If I selected the WebBrowser button, its border will change to green, indicating that it is active. Once de-selected the mouse over will NO longer work on it. The de-selecting is done by selecting another button.

[image: Images Used as Buttons]

**This is my mouse over code**

```
Private Sub WebBrowserNewButt_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
''Set WebBrowserNewButt Border Colour Green
If WebBrowserNewButt.BorderColor <> 8435998 Then
   Me.WebBrowserNewButt.BorderColor = 8435998

    ''Grey Borders
    Me.MainMenuButton.BorderColor = -2147483627
    Me.SecondMenuButton.BorderColor = -2147483627
    Me.EmailButton.BorderColor = -2147483627
    Me.SearchButton.BorderColor = -2147483627
    Me.SaveNewButton.BorderColor = -2147483627
End If
End Sub
```

Onclick code

```
Private Sub WebBrowserNewButt_click()
Me.WebBrowserNewButt.BorderColor = 8435998 'GREEN BORDER

'GREY BORDERS, for all other images(buttons)
    Me.MainMenuButton.BorderColor = -2147483627
    Me.SecondMenuButton.BorderColor = -2147483627
    Me.EmailButton.BorderColor = -2147483627
    Me.SearchButton.BorderColor = -2147483627
    Me.SaveNewButton.BorderColor = -2147483627
    UserForm1.Repaint

'MULTIPAGES
Me.MultiPage1.Pages(0).Visible = True 
    MultiPage1.Value = 0

Me.MultiPage1.Pages(1).Visible = False 
Me.MultiPage1.Pages(2).Visible = False 
Me.MultiPage1.Pages(3).Visible = False 
Me.MultiPage1.Pages(4).Visible = False 
End Sub
```

**What I have tried so far.**

- I have tried it with and without the Me.  (I left it on Me.)
- I have tried to google the answer
- I have tried it without repaint, did not work without repaint, repaint
  does cause the images to flash.
- I have tried to place the change boarder colour in the multi-page, so when active that multi page is
  *visible = true* then the image border colour will change, could not get it to work.
- I removed the option of turning the borders to Grey on hover, that did not fix the problem.

The multi-pages will not have their tabs set to visible.

Please could someone advise on what to do.

As always thanks in advance.

Comment: The only way I can get it to work is via Repaint, how this cause other objects on the userform to flash. If some know how to stop the flashing on repaint, then that would help. I tried to google the answer but everything I found was on Application. ScreenUpdating, which was no good

Comment: I ok I have fixed this, well more of a work around. That is why I have not listed this as an answer. I have placed all the buttons into an Active Control X frame and set the layout to Flat which changes the Borders to NONE. I also used the UserForm1.Repaint as a refresh. The frame has stoppend the flicker and the mouseover works. I will need to place other items into frames that are still flickering as the frame resolves the mouseover flickering.